# When can one represent the conditional expectation $E[X|Y]$ as $g(Y)$ with continuous $g$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Given two random variables $X$ and $Y$ we know that $E[X|Y] = g(Y)$ where $g$ is a Borel function. Is it a good question to ask under which condition there exists a function $g$ which will be continuous, Lipschitz etc.?

Comment: Not really--first of all because every other function equal to $g$ on a subset of full measure with respect to the distribution of $Y$, is also a solution.

Comment: @Did: can we at least talk about whether at least one such function exist ?

Comment: Yes we can--what for? (Just trying to understand where you are heading for...)

Comment: @Did: for stochastic approximation algorithm we need such condition as assumption, but I have not seen any book talking about what are the conditions under which such assumption is satisfied.

Comment: OK. Some specific families of distributions excepted (gaussian, most notably), I am not overly optimistic... :-)